# ScriptResource.axd 404 error ONLY on subdomains

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have setup my website (ASP.NET 4.0) with AJAX, running with no problems at all.

When I test my website locally and on my main top level domain, there are no problems.

When I'm on a subdomain page, AJAX client side framework fails to load. I observed the problem deeply and found that whenever I'm on a subdomain page, WebResource.axd DOES load but ScriptResource.axd DOESN'T load (returns 404 Not Found error). I think I should modify some entries at web.config file, but I have no idea on what to do?

If you want to see the problem live, go to www.123tiendas.com/subdominios/articulo/default.aspx?id=2020 and there's no problem. Go to  www.articulo.123tiendas.com/?id=2020 and you'll see the problem. (use any web developer tools to see what is returned)

`GET http://articulo.123tiendas.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=BHVdt7ZKRNgWkcmIzZPX-cQ…NHSxpLPXcqbJyg46pdNsVlEnaL_JpR-IQ0IdhPXwT575CanbqzCN8vtDLDFF9A2&t=48e38e19 404 (Not Found) articulo.123tiendas.com:119`

Comment: How are these websites arranged in IIS?  Does one website live inside the other website's folder structure?

Comment: Yes, HTML/Subdominios/Articulo/default.aspx and the subdomain www.articulo.123tiendas.com points to HTML/Subdominios/Articulo/""default.aspx"" <-- here. Sorry for my bad English